# Inconsistent reputation count

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I was looking at [my profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299592/amurra) and noticed that in the reputation section I had a +25 and shaded green background for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140904/asp-net-and-html-5) which would make me believe that I received one upvote and my answer was accepted.

Looking at the Answers section in my profile page sorted by newest I noticed that question had a 2 next to it with no shaded green background which would led me to believe I have two upvotes with my answer not being accepted.

[image: Answers and Rep sections]

Looking at the drop down when you hover over your user name at the top of the site I see a +35 for this question. That makes me believe I have two upvotes with my answer being accepted.

[image: Drop down selection]

When I go to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140904/asp-net-and-html-5) page I see that I have two upvotes, but my answer is not marked as the answer. Why am I seeing three different reputations for this question and which one is the right one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So a few things happened here. Thanks for reporting this! ♪

Your reputation report says "+25" because it's only tracking by day. You got one upvote on one day, and another on the day you got accepted. So you'll only see the second day's events, which are +25.

Your dropdown report is the most correct. It tracks the most recent changes, regardless of time barriers. As such, even though the +35 occurred over two days, there aren't any other events to take precedence so it can show you the +35.

The lack of acceptance was caused by a deadlock happening at the time the acceptance vote was cast. As such, timeline reports that the event happened and you got reputation, but the answer is not considered accepted and the question is not recognized as having an accepted answer. This has since been fixed (with thanks to Nick Craver), so you should see the acceptance mark on the post, and a green square in your profile's answer section as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks I see that it is fixed now.